# How to paint according to qStylesheet in QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qt5, qstyleditemdelegate

I want to subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and modify it with QStyleSheets. I dont have any clue of how to get it to work. I tried plenty of hours to just display anything, looking like I defined in the qss. In priciple it has to work, because when I call the base class implementation of `paint(QPainter*, const QStyleOptionViewItem &, const QModelIndex&)` the list items look like defined. Well, now how can I apply the stylesheet in the delegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything has to be done through QStyle. E.g. in a QListView to draw the background:

```
QStyle *style = option.widget->style();
style->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelItemViewItem, &option, painter, option.widget);
```

There are a lot of other drawXYZ(..) functions. See [QStyle docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstyle.html).